# Ubercart most selling product in drupal 7

Tags: 7, views, ubercart

I'm using Drupal 7 on my site with [Ubercart 7.x - 3.4.](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart) I want is an existing module or a view customization tips to make the most selling / best selling product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a view Export

```
$view = new view;
$view->name = 'best_sellers';
$view->description = 'Best Sellers';
$view->tag = 'Best Sellers';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Best Sellers';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0-alpha1';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Defaults */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Defaults', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '5';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Field: Fields: uc_product_image */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['entity_id']['id'] = 'entity_id';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['entity_id']['table'] = 'field_data_uc_product_image';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['entity_id']['field'] = 'entity_id';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['entity_id']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['entity_id']['alter']['alter_text'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['entity_id']['alter']['make_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['entity_id']['alter']['absolute'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['entity_id']['alter']['trim'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['entity_id']['alter']['word_boundary'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['entity_id']['alter']['ellipsis'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['entity_id']['alter']['strip_tags'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['entity_id']['alter']['html'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['entity_id']['element_label_colon'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['entity_id']['element_default_classes'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['entity_id']['hide_empty'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['entity_id']['empty_zero'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['entity_id']['click_sort_column'] = 'fid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['entity_id']['settings'] = array(
  'image_style' => 'thumbnail',
  'image_link' => 'content',
);
/* Field: Node: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['alter_text'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['make_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['absolute'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['trim'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['strip_tags'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['html'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_label_colon'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_default_classes'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['hide_empty'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['empty_zero'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['link_to_node'] = 1;
/* Field: Product: Buy it now button */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['buyitnowbutton']['id'] = 'buyitnowbutton';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['buyitnowbutton']['table'] = 'uc_products';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['buyitnowbutton']['field'] = 'buyitnowbutton';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['buyitnowbutton']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['buyitnowbutton']['alter']['alter_text'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['buyitnowbutton']['alter']['make_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['buyitnowbutton']['alter']['absolute'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['buyitnowbutton']['alter']['trim'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['buyitnowbutton']['alter']['word_boundary'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['buyitnowbutton']['alter']['ellipsis'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['buyitnowbutton']['alter']['strip_tags'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['buyitnowbutton']['alter']['html'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['buyitnowbutton']['element_label_colon'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['buyitnowbutton']['element_default_classes'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['buyitnowbutton']['hide_empty'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['buyitnowbutton']['empty_zero'] = 0;
/* Field: Product: Sell price */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['sell_price']['id'] = 'sell_price';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['sell_price']['table'] = 'uc_products';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['sell_price']['field'] = 'sell_price';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['sell_price']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['sell_price']['alter']['alter_text'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['sell_price']['alter']['make_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['sell_price']['alter']['absolute'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['sell_price']['alter']['trim'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['sell_price']['alter']['word_boundary'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['sell_price']['alter']['ellipsis'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['sell_price']['alter']['strip_tags'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['sell_price']['alter']['html'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['sell_price']['element_label_colon'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['sell_price']['element_default_classes'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['sell_price']['hide_empty'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['sell_price']['empty_zero'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['sell_price']['set_precision'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['sell_price']['precision'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['sell_price']['format_plural'] = 0;
/* Sort criterion: Order product: Qty */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['qty']['id'] = 'qty';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['qty']['table'] = 'uc_order_products';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['qty']['field'] = 'qty';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['qty']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter: Node: Is a product */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['is_product']['id'] = 'is_product';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['is_product']['table'] = 'uc_products';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['is_product']['field'] = 'is_product';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['is_product']['value'] = '1';

/* Display: Block */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'best_sellers');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['title'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Best Sellers';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['css_class'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['css_class'] = 'new-product-block';
$handler->display->display_options['block_description'] = 'Best Sellers';
$translatables['best_sellers'] = array(
  t('Defaults'),
  t('more'),
  t('Apply'),
  t('Reset'),
  t('Sort By'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('.'),
  t(','),
  t('Block'),
  t('Best Sellers'),
);
```

**How to**

1. Login to Drupal as an administrator. Go to Structure > Views.
2. Click “Import View from Code”

[Add "Popular Products" view](http://drupal.org/node/1339910)

Comment: wow! worked like never did before

Comment: My pleasure ... :)

Comment: If I import this code, what is the next step, will it create a new view ?

Comment: @Bala yes it will

Comment: Disclaimer: This view does not show 'Most Popular' or 'Best Selling' products.

It has sort on 'qty' in 'uc_order_products' table. This sort doesn't import because it's a 'node' view and 'uc_order_products' is part of the 'Order Products' bundle. Even if this sort was a part of the view, it wouldn't show most popular products because that data is per product per order, not per product overall.

The reason a 'Best Sellers' view doesn't exist is because it's actually very hard to track this statistic through views (not easy with custom code either).

Comment: @leexonline is correct

Comment: Will this view work if there is no fix product stock is added?

Answer (score 0):

[easyrec for ubercart](https://drupal.org/project/easyrec_for_ubercart) integrates the product recommender functionality of easyrec (http://easyrec.org/) into an ubercart shop. It provides Drupal Blocks for the display of recommendations or product rankings. Also you can **integrate with views 3**.

Available Blocks

> - easyrec: other users also bought
> - easyrec: other users also viewed
> - easyrec: recommendations for user
> - **easyrec: most bought items**
> - easyrec: most viewed items

The Blocks are fully style-able using the module administration interface. Or can use one of the following drawing callbacks:

> - Views 3 support
> - Jquery Carousel
> - Image List
> - Text List
> - create your own using javascript or the drupal hook