# Is there a view for top selling products, including product kits?

Tags: views, ubercart

I'm looking for a view to list top selling Ubercart 3 products and product kits.
It would be a BIG plus if the view can include an image field and a taxonomy field.

I have checked this articles but didn't get what I'm looking for

http://drupal.org/node/1339910

[Ubercart most selling product in drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/66594/ubercart-most-selling-product-in-drupal-7)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[easyrec for ubercart](https://drupal.org/project/easyrec_for_ubercart) module provides the functionality for most selling products(**most bought items**) and it also provide the following options as blocks.

Available Blocks

```
easyrec: other users also bought
easyrec: other users also viewed
easyrec: recommendations for user
easyrec: most bought items
easyrec: most viewed items
```

> To use the "easyrec for ubercart" module a shop owner needs access to
>   an easyrec server. It's possible to register a free easyrec account at
>   http://easyrec.org/ if the owner cannot host his/her own. After
>   creating an account on the easyrec server and a 'tenant' account for
>   the specific shop, the shop owner just copies the tenantId and apiKey
>   into the drupal module's administration interface to enable
>   recommendations for the ubercart shop.

Comment: I installed easyrec, after entering the api key and Tenant ID, when I click save config I get the following message

"Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /admin/config/services/easyrec on this server."

Comment: @Stoan check this it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server

Comment: @Stoan change the easyrec url https://drupal.org/files/issues/easyrec_for_ubercart_settings.png